# Display present working directory in Terminal

Tags: bash, prompt

This is what I presently see in Mac Terminal as always

> EN-AAABBBB:~ username$

My understanding is that `EN-AAABBBB` is my Mac name, followed by username.
But I would like to transform this into this format

> username@pwd$

How do I achieve this? Other customization tips are welcome :) [Colors etc..]

*Note*:
I tried adding `PS1='\u@ \W \$ '` to `.bash_profile`, and am now getting the result as

> username@ ~ $

`\w or \W` should display working directory, but it is not. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16728/hide-current-working-directory-in-terminal) was useful in figuring out how to accomplish this.

This is what I'm using:

```
PS1="\H@\u: \$(pwd)> "
```

- `\H` stands for Hostname
- `\u` stands for username
- `\$(pwd)` prints the present working directory.

Comment: ~ is your /home/user directory so what you were doing was working. If you have a directory below, had you put \w instead of $(pwd), that would show you ~/directory_below. You may also try adding something like `[$?]` to your line which would show you the exit status of the last command, in brackets...